# Neo4j-Cypher : Is it possible to pass dynamically reuired fields of node in cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to find out the way to pass return parameters dynamically so i can reuse query for multiple cases like in one case i need two fields of node and in an another case i need three fields like

So here i need two properties **id and name** of user

```
Match (n:User) where id(n)={0} return n = {1};   //cypher params to pass= {0=1,1={id(n) as id,n.name as name}};
```

here, i need three properties of user,

```
Match (n:User) where id(n)={0} return n = {1};   //cypher params to pass= {0=1,1={id(n) as id,n.name as name,n.active as active}};
```

So is it possible to pass return parameters dynamically.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to return a different set of values at the end of your query, depending on a parameter you pass to the query? You can achieve this quite easily in cypher, using something like the below!

Fixture for the example:

```
CREATE (u:ExampleUser { name: "Test User" })
```

Query:

```
WITH 0 AS return_type  // change to 1 to see just name!
MATCH (u:ExampleUser) WHERE u.name = "Test User"
WITH 
  CASE return_type
    WHEN 0 THEN { name: u.name, id: id(u) }
    WHEN 1 THEN { name: u.name }
  END AS return_value
RETURN return_value
```

Here we use the `CASE` operator to set the value of `return_type` as one of either two mappings, depending on the value of `return_type`. You can replace the `0` in the example with a `1` to get just the name. Likewise, replace with a parameter to change the output dynamically. You can also add more `WHEN x THEN y` clauses as needed.

Your output will be a mapping called `return_value`.